# Conditional SELECT Statement MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016, jet

Is there any way to create a statement similar to this in MS-Access SQL?

```
IF (STATEMENT)
    SELECT * FROM tbl1
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM tbl2
```

I'm working on a legacy database and being able to do this will help optimize a deeply nested query that has a UNION ALL at it's root. By removing this union that isn't needed in 99% of cases the runtime is greatly decreased.

I've been researching and experimenting for 2 days and so far the closest thing I have found that looks like it could work is BEGIN and END statements that run off IF statements in Transact SQL, but unfortunately I've had no luck finding anything for Ms-Access SQL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to create two queries, and then use VBA to determine which query to use.

Comment: There are multiple way to solve that (SQL, VBA, mix of 2s) but since we haven't seen the whole query and their results, its a bit difficult to help

Comment: @ThomasG, Typically I would use VBA but since it's a child query I was hoping to just make the change within the query itself to avoid having to modify 24 other queries that are pulling from it. It's nothing special, it's just a Union query that is joining a live table with an archive table, and I don't want that archive table to be there unless it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`, assuming the two tables have the same columns:

```
select *
from tbl1
where <statement>
union all
select *
from tbl2
where not <statement>
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to use this to replace a UNION ALL when I set a flag, as the union is currently bloating the runtime.

I had tried adding a WHERE clause in the child of the union query and it didn't result in any speed increases, but I'll give that a try and see if having it within the union itself will help speed things up. Once I've tested it I'll post an update.

Comment: After testing it looks like it unfortunately does not help in decreasing runtime.